# Running cucumber tests through Intelli-J 10.5.3?

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea, rubygems, cucumber, rvm

When I try to run cucumber tests with Ruby `1.9.3-p0`, I get this:

`Cucumber gem 'cucumber(1.1.3) isn't supported by graphical test runner, please use verison >= '0.3.7' for 'RVM: ruby-1.9.3-p0' SDK`

Is there any way to get around this? I'd like to be able to run and debug tests from within my IDE.

Comment: Maybe you should try version >= '0.3.7'?

Comment: guess I overread that one, sry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue fixed after 10.5.3, [check this bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RUBY-9453) for workarounds.